# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly in Plugin.FirebasePushNotification

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

I am trying to release the application on Android using Linker to reduce the apk size.

When I use None I don´t have problem.

When I use SDK Assemblies Only I get the next error:

```
   Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Plugin.FirebasePushNotification.FirebasePushNotificationManager::Subscribe(System.String)' in assembly: 'Plugin.FirebasePushNotification.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging::SubscribeToTopic(System.String)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What are you doing to your application to take 100+MB ?

Comment: updated question. but almost 100 MB

Comment: Are you using official firebase plugin? which version?

Comment: I am using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification 2.3.5 Latest stable version

Comment: You can check about app size reduction here: https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/reducing-the-app-size-in-xamarin-deep-dive-7ddc9cb12688 and about linking here: https://medium.com/@harrycblum/reduce-your-xamarin-app-size-with-linking-26247edc87f6

Comment: @Narendra you fixed it? If yes, how?

Comment: There is an official issue which you will find here: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/252